# Is packaging an Electron-builder via npm (not yarn) possible?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, npm, electron, electron-builder

I have create a python3 app using the Electron environment (itself based on Node.js).
For this app, the dependencies have been installed using npm and my app launches using the `npm start` command.

Following the [documentation of Electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging), it seems that Electron-builder is the best option for distributing my app for all platforms. Unfortunately, the [installation guide](https://www.electron.build/#installation) recommends using yarn, not npm as npm might not be working properly : [see related ticket](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1147#issuecomment-276284477)

Now my question is: As the ticket is rather old (2017), is it now possible to make it work with npm ? So yes how ?

If it is not possible to make it work with npm, how do I transition my code to yarn ?

For info:
The reason I ask is because I get a BIIIIIG error message when I run the command `npm run dist`.
If needed I can edit the post to include it (alongside my package.json file)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: adding error and package.json**

```
{
  "name": "APP_NAME",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The first version of APP_NAME's GUI.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": "https://docenhance.com",
  "author": "DocEnhance <nootaku@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "start": "npm install && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.docenhance.APP_NAME",
    "productName": "APP_NAME - PROJECT_NAME",
    "linux": {
      "target": "deb",
      "icon": "build/icon.icns",
      "category": "Office"
    }
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "electron": "^4.0.7",
    "electron-builder": "^20.39.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

The error file can be found [HERE](https://nofile.io/f/MH7sjKFyrGw/error.txt).

Comment: I sure think the error message would be helpful :D While your at it, also post your package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `npm`. The yargs issue is explained [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3751).

Your error messages tell you . . . what the errors are.

> error output:[ERROR] Unknown input file format:
>   /home/MYUSERNAME/Documents/APP_DIRECTORY/dist/.icon-set/icon_ICN#.jp2
>           Known file formats are *.j2k, *.jp2, *.jpc or *.jpt

I don't use or work on Linux so I don't know for sure if this is the case, but you are specifying a `.icns` file format for your icon. That is an [OSX icon file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format). Your error message says that Electron Builder doesn't know what to do with that (on Linux).

```
"linux": {
      "target": "deb",
      "icon": "build/icon.icns",
      "category": "Office"
    }
```

---

The rest of the scary error text likely just cascades from that.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Though I would like to come back on that error: In the [documentaton](https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux) I can read the following:
"The path to icon set directory or one png file, relative to the build resources or to the project directory. The icon filename must contain the size (e.g. 32x32.png) of the icon. By default will be generated automatically based on the macOS icns file."

So i tried it out by creating a "mac" property in my package.json and inserting the icns file there. But i get  the same error. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Nootaku - it looks like there are some [issues](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2577). I don't work on Linux but it looks like declaring the icon **outside** of the target specification object works for those folks.

Comment: what will be the command we will place inside build for npm version of "yarn electron-builder"?